# Using PHP CURL to display PDF file is just producing strange text

Tags: php, curl, pdf-generation

I'm using PHP CURL to access PDF files, and everything is working properly with the exception of the end result being unreadable.  My code is as follows:

```
$cookie = 'cookies.txt';
$timeout = 30;
$url = "http://www.somesite.com/sample_report.pdf";

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Encoding: none','Content-Type: application/pdf')); 

$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;
```

When I just manually enter the URL into the browser, the PDF properly displays. But when using CURL, it displays pages of gibberish text.

Looking at the code view in the browser, I see a lot of lines like these:

```
5 0 obj
<</Length 6 0 R/Filter /FlateDecode>>
stream
```

And on the page where the .pdf should display, is the following code:

```
<body>
    <p>
      <object id='mypdf' type='application/pdf' width='100%' height='90%' data='sample_report.pdf'>
      </object>
   </p>
</body>
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try it with this (keep your first 3 lines the same)

```
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Encoding: none','Content-Type: application/pdf')); 

header('Content-type: application/pdf');
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
```

The line I commented out doesn't appear to be doing anything. I added the "header" line. If I take that line out, I get a page of gibberish as you do. If it is still saying "headers already sent", there must be something setting a header elsewhere.

EDIT:

I would also suggest changing this:

```
<object id='mypdf' type='application/pdf' width='100%' height='90%' data='sample_report.pdf'></object>
```

To this:

```
<iframe src="sample_report.pdf" width="100%" height="90%"></iframe>
```

Or, if your PHP script is called sample_report.pdf (for instance) try changing iframe src to sample_report.php.

Comment: That got rid of all the gibberish text, but it didn't display any error, or anything for that matter.

Comment: That was just to see if any errors were occurring before it displayed the PDF. I guess not. You can take out the exit. See revised answer for an additional suggestion

Comment: When I make the revision with the header, it gives the error of "headers already sent".

Comment: Could you post more of the code? Are you using header() prior to executing the code you posted?

Comment: See if this makes any difference.

Comment: I tried that and it worked. Thanks!  I was hoping that putting that header would automatically download it to the person's computer, but for some reason it doesn't.  Is there anything else that could be added to make it do that?  Thanks again.

Comment: Great! Could you mark this as a correct answer please so people can see it's resolved? Thanks! As for the download to the user's computer, that might be another question entirely, but I'll add one further edit to my answer as I think I might know why that isn't doing what you're expecting.